# CSS: What is it called when a page has a page underneath it on its left and right sides?

Tags: css

For example, [on this site](http://www.muenchen.de/int/en/sights.html) there is the main content in the center, and pure white background on the far right and left. What is this design styling called? How can I do this with CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it has a name. It's a container with a defined width centered in the middle.

Try with this:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    //Content here
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body{
    background-color:#eee;
}
.container{
    width:960px;
    margin:auto;
    background-color:#fff;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how it's called or if it has a name (I just call it fixed width, centred content), but it is achieved like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>My Site</title>

<main>
  <!-- Your main content goes here -->
</main>
```

```
body {
  /* The color of the stripes left and right */
  background-color: white;
}
main {
  /* Define the width here */
  max-width: 960px;
  /* Center it */
  margin: 0 auto;
  /* Your content background */
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  /* Optionally add separating lines and shadow: */
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  border-top: none;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #aaa;
}
```